# Consuming Webservice in .NET (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

When creating a Service Reference in Visual Studio 2012 to a remote webservice, provided by JAX (Java webservice library), a "simple" complex object is not being created properly in the generated stubs.

Complex objects that contain multiple child elements are created correctly.. for example:

```
<xs:complexType name="condition">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="fieldId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="operator" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="value1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="value2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

gets created successfully, where the .NET class called **condition** is created, with field, operator, value1 and value2 as members.

However the object defined by:

```
<xs:complexType name="dataRow">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="dataValue" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

doesn't get created at all.

An array of **dataRow** objects is referenced from another complex object:

```
<xs:complexType name="response">
  <xs:sequence>
      ...
    <xs:element name="results" type="tns:dataRow" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      ...
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

.NET creates this as:

```
Private results()() As String
```

This seems to have replaced the array of **dataRow**'s with a single multi-dimensional String array.

There are no compilation errors, but when trying to use this service I get the runtime error:

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string[]' to 'string'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'
```

I can edit the generated References file, where I change **GetType(String)** to **GetType(String())** in:

```
 <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable:=True, Order:=47), _
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("dataValue", GetType(String()), Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> _
    Public Property results() As String()()
        Get
            Return Me.resultsField
        End Get
        Set(value As String()())
            Me.resultsField = value
            Me.RaisePropertyChanged("results")
        End Set
    End Property
```

This causes the code to not throw runtime errors, but the items returned from the webservice are blank. The result seems to be an array of blank strings (6 in this case), when it should be a multi-dimensional array (a list of 6 String arrays), with populated strings.

I could probably edit the generated **references** file to force the **dataRow** to be generated. If there is an easy way to make this happen automatically in the auto generated stubs I'd prefer to do that.

I am not familiar with the intricacies of consuming webservices in .NET. Any advice on getting this to work would be appreciated.

I have consumed this webservice in other languages successfully without manual intervention.

Comment: try to use `svcutility` to generate the proxy class.

Comment: I assume you mean svcutil. With default settings this generates the same client side stubs as Visual Studio and the same issues. I will see if there are any svcutil parameters that can alter the generated code.